# How to create a packet for serial communication with specific requirements?

Tags: c++, c, serial-port, byte, bit

I want to communicate with a serial-device. The individual packets are sent with a continuously ascending byte sequence, i.e. the first byte of the packet is PacCmd and the last byte of a packet is CheckSum. The individual bytes are INTEL coded (Little Endian), i.e. the LSB is sent first. The INTEL coding is used everywhere where the packet's individual data elements consist of more than one byte (PacCmd, Data).

The datapack is described as follows:

```
DataPac ::= { PacCmd + DataLen + { DataByte } } + CheckSum
PacCmd - 2 Byte unsigned integer = unsigned short
DataLen - 1 Byte unsigned integer = unsigned char/uint8_t
DataByte - x Byte = Data to send/receive = mixed
CheckSum - 1 Byte unsigned integer = unsigned char/uint8_t
```

This is no problem. But the PacCmd is a problem. It consists of 3 Bits for control and a 13 bit integer value, the command. The description of PacCmd:

```
PacCmd ::= ( ReqBit | RspBit | MoreDataBit ) + Cmd
ReqBit - 1 Bit: If set, an acknowledgement is requested from the receiver

RspBit - 1 Bit: If set, this data packet is to be interpreted as an acknowledgement

MoreDataBit - 1 Bit: If set, an additional PacCmd field follows subsequent to the data belonging to this command

Cmd - 13 Bits Unsigned Integer: Identification via the content of the data field of this packet (only if the RspBit is not set)
```

My question is: How can I interpret the value of Cmd? How can I extract the 3 bits and the 13 bits integer? How can I set the 3 bits and the 13 bits integer? Any example-code on how to extract the information? Just use the bitwise operator `&`? What does the Little Endian do with that?

Comment: What does the Little Endian do with PacCmd - you need to ask communication protocol author. It is really not clear. Everything else can be solved using bitwise operations or bitfields.

Comment: Thanks! You have an example on how to extract the 3 bits for rsp, req and moredata and the 13 bits integer? Would be really helpful.

Comment: Yes, just use the & operator.  There's a lot more to a protocol, you are just scratching the surface.  Look at the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osi_model) for reference.  The serial port is layer 1, what you wrote up is layer 2, the way you are supposed to interpret ACKs and deal with errors is layer 4, the meaning of Cmd is layer 7.